# How to click on a link with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, triggers, click

I'm trying to trigger a click on a link, but it only runs the ng-click
From MyScript.js:

```
$timeout(function () {
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#cancelButton')).triggerHandler('click');
        }, 0);
```

And from Index.cshtml:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="abortCart()" id="cancelButton"><input class="popupButton" type="button" value="Anuluj" /></a>
```

I know that the way I did with

```
<a...><input... /></a>
```

is wrong,
but the important thing is: how to it to click the link and the ng-click?

Comment: have you tried to trigger your route inside your click function?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple program to navigate to the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="ctrl">
            Redirect to <a href="#" ng-click="redirect()">Click Me!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $log, $window) {
            $scope.redirect = function () {
                var url = "http://www.google.com";
                $window.location.href = url;
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you wanted?